# How the location of target impacting the behaviour of makefile

Tags: makefile

I wrote a simple Makefile as below:

```
.PHONY: all A B
A:
    @echo "in target A"

B:
    @echo "in target B"

all: A B
```

the output is

```
in target A
```

but if I modified the Makefile as below:

```
.PHONY: all A B
all: A B

A:
    @echo "in target A"

B:
    @echo "in target B"
```

the output become

```
in target A
in target B
```

what part of Makefile manual should I read more carefully to understand the difference?

Comment: `make` has the concept of a [default goal](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Arguments-to-Specify-the-Goals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what part of Makefile manual should I read more carefully to understand the difference?

Which part of the manual to study depend on which `make` manual you are reading, but the explanation for the behavior you observe is simple: when you run `make` without designating any targets to build, `make` builds the *default target*, which is the first target appearing in the makefile whose name does not consist of a period ('.') followed by uppercase letters.

In particular, the target name "all" has no special significance to `make`. Its use is simply a widespread convention, and to make the `all` target work as you expect (that is, for it to be the default target), it must be positioned first in the makefile.  There are makefiles that have an "all" target that is intentionally positioned elsewhere so that a different one is the default.  When it's not the default, you can still build it explicitly, of course, by naming it on the command line: `make all`.

Answer (score 0):

when running `make` without any goal, the first goal in out Makefile will be exectued.

You can manage the default goal using `.DEFAULT_GOAL` variable.
Read https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html for more information